# Need help sorting descending in PHP; nothing seems to work

Tags: php, sorting

I have a photo album style page setup with thumbnails and links. The problem is the thumbnails are not matching the folder and the link it's connected with due to some sort of sorting issue. The page can be viewed at http://www.remixnightclub.net/album.php as well as the code. Any ideas on what I can try to get this to work correctly? I'm relatively new to php if that's not too obvious.

```
//if no album selected
if (!$get_album)
{
    echo "<b>Select an album:</b><p />";

    //find each album and display as links
    $y = 0;
    $handle = opendir($base); 

    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
    {
        if (is_dir($base."/".$file) && $file !="." && $file !=".." && $file != $thumbs)
        {
            echo "<table style='display:inline;' class='nav'><tr><td align='center'><a href='$page?album=$file'><img src='$base/$thumbs/$images[$i]'></a><br /><li><a href='$page?album=$file'>".$file."</a></li></td></tr></table>";
            $i++;

            if ($y==$column1)
                echo "<br />";

            $y = 0;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

I am not using a database.

Comment: Can't help you if you don't supply any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `readdir` function returns directory entries in essentially random order; programs like `ls` go to the trouble of sorting them before displaying them, but they're not sorted naturally in the file system.  Read them into an array and sort that before iterating through it.

Example:

```
    $files = array();
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
    {
        if (is_dir($base."/".$file) && $file !="." && $file !=".." && $file != $thumbs)
        {
            array_push($files, $file);
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);

    rsort($files);

    foreach ($files as $file)
```

etc.

Comment: This method works for me, but I have a problem with the thumbnails when using it because it doesn't loop back around to pickup another image. Is there a different method that can be used for adding thumbnails to a sorted array?

Comment: Nevermind; that was easy...I figured it out. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be to read the whole directory using [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php). `glob` will sort your files for you:

```
$files = glob($base);
foreach ($files as $file)
{
  // etc.
```

You can even specify a pattern to get only the files you want, excluding the thumbs.

**Edit:** If you want descending order, you would need to reverse the result:

```
$files = glob($base);
$inverse_files = array_reverse($files);
```